Why does `while let` in a Future implementation trigger the Waker, but `if let` does not?
I've been working on a Future implementation in Rust, and I've encountered behavior I don't fully understand. Specifically, I'm using std::sync::mpsc::Receiver inside the poll method, and I'm trying to decide between while let and if let for receiving messages.
Here's the simplified version of my poll method:
fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, _cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
    let this = self.get_mut();

    // Option 1: Using `while let`
    while let Ok(new_attributes) = this.receiver.try_recv() {
        // Process the message
    }

    // Option 2: Using `if let`
    if let Ok(new_attributes) = this.receiver.try_recv() {
        // Process the message
    }

    Poll::Pending
}

What I’ve Observed
When I use while let, everything seems to work as expected: the Future is re-polled when new messages arrive. However, when I use if let, the Future appears to hang and never wakes up again, even when new messages are available.
My Understanding
I know that the Waker is supposed to be used to notify the executor that the Future should be re-polled. Given that my poll function always returns Poll::Pending, I would expect the Future to continue being polled repeatedly unless the process itself stops. However, I don't understand why while let ensures the Waker is triggered correctly, whereas if let does not seem to do the same.
Additional Context
The Future is spawned like this:
ctx.task_executor()
    .spawn_critical_blocking("transaction execution service", Box::pin(fut_struct));

The spawn_critical_blocking function works as follows:
pub fn spawn_critical_blocking<F>(&self, name: &'static str, fut: F) -> JoinHandle<()>
where
    F: Future<Output = ()> + Send + 'static,
{
    self.spawn_critical_as(name, fut, TaskKind::Blocking)
}

And internally:
fn spawn_critical_as<F>(
    &self,
    name: &'static str,
    fut: F,
    task_kind: TaskKind,
) -> JoinHandle<()>
where
    F: Future<Output = ()> + Send + 'static,
{
    // Wrapping the future and handling task errors
    let task = std::panic::AssertUnwindSafe(fut)
        .catch_unwind()
        .map_err(...);

    let task = async move {
        // Handling task shutdown and execution
        let task = pin!(task);
        let _ = select(on_shutdown, task).await;
    };

    self.spawn_on_rt(task, task_kind)
}

The spawn_on_rt method then uses spawn_blocking.
My Question

Why does using while let ensure that the Waker is triggered, but using if let
does

not?

What is the underlying mechanism that causes this difference in behavior?

Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Can you provide a code sample that exhibits the behavior you describe? You aren't using the Context so nothing should be waking up your future.

Before I address your questions, I'd like to challenge one of your assumptions:

Given that my poll function always returns Poll::Pending, I would expect the Future to continue being polled repeatedly

This, while technically possible, is not at all to be expected. Normal async runtimes (like tokio) attempt to be efficient by only polling when progress has been made, as signaled using the Waker conveyed by the Context.
Notice that you never use the Context argument which, unless your future always returns Poll::Ready immediately, is an error, as there is no reliable reason for your poll function to ever be called again. (technically it's possible for it to be called again, because async runtimes may spuriously poll futures, but you shouldn't ever rely on that!)

Why does using while let ensure that the Waker is triggered, but using if let does not?

There is nothing about while let that is guaranteed to trigger the Waker. It is for this reason that the following code doesn't work:
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::future::Future;
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver};

struct Demo{
    receiver: Receiver<()>,
}

impl Future for Demo {
    type Output = ();
    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, _cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let this = self.get_mut();
        println!("poll");
    
        // Option 1: Using `while let`
        while let Ok(_) = this.receiver.try_recv() {
            println!("processing");
            // Process the message
        }
    
        Poll::Pending
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() {
    let (sender, receiver) = channel();
    let demo = Demo{receiver};
    let thread = std::thread::spawn(move || {
        sender.send(()).unwrap();
    });
    println!("before");
    demo.await;
    println!("after");
    thread.join().unwrap();
}

Output:
before
poll


What is the underlying mechanism that causes this difference in behavior?

The only difference between if let and while let is that the latter will continue to read from the channel if there are more messages buffered. An alternative, more plausible, explanation for what you are seeing is that while let allows a single invocation of poll to process multiple messages while doing nothing to schedule a subsequent invocation of poll.
How to fix
The main issue with your code is that you are trying to use as synchronous channel implementation from the standard library in an async context; They're incompatible, and mixing them in this way is incorrect and unreliable. You should switch to an async-based channel such as tokio::sync::mpsc:
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::future::Future;
use tokio::sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver};

struct Demo{
    receiver: Receiver<()>,
}

impl Future for Demo {
    type Output = ();
    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let this = self.get_mut();
        
        println!("poll");
    
        if let Poll::Ready(result) = this.receiver.poll_recv(cx) {
            if let Some(_message) = result {
                println!("processed");
            } else {
                println!("channel closed");
            }
            return Poll::Ready(());
        }
    
        Poll::Pending
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() {
    let (sender, receiver) = channel(10);
    let demo = Demo{receiver};
    let task = tokio::spawn(async move {
        sender.send(()).await.unwrap();
    });
    println!("before");
    demo.await;
    println!("after");
    task.await.unwrap();
}

Notice how receiving on the channel now involves an inner poll-like call that takes the Context as an argument. If there is not currently a message to receive, the Waker will be associated with the channel (in an implementation-specific way) such that it may cause the future to be polled when a message arrives.
Output:
before
poll
poll
processsed
after

Notice there are two polls. Presumably, the first one encountered no message to receive. Proper use of async polling meant that the future was productively polled again.

Thanks for you explanation. I've added additional context

@narumi sure! FWIW, nothing about the additional context you added *so far* changes my answer. Making your original poll function make sense would require a non-standard async executor that aggressively calls poll without being woken up. I see no reason to believe you are using such a non-standard async executor but, if you were, you should switch to a normal one.

To elaborate further, the receiver is a very simple channel that receives one message per second. Given the simplicity of this channel, I thought using std instead of tokio would be more efficient. However, based on your explanation, my confusion arises from the fact that while let seems to work exactly as I intended: it continuously executes the logic every time a message arrives, even if the messages only come once per second.

If, as you mentioned, returning Poll::Pending means that the Waker will no longer wake the Future(since I am not using Context), then how is it possible for it to continue working as expected?

Thanks for elaborating, but it doesn't change the fact that your code is wrong for the reasons I described and could be fixed in the way I described. Re "will no longer wake; how is it possible..." I never said the Future is guaranteed to never wake. I just said there is "no reason" (in other words, "no reliable, legitimate reason") for it to wake. It's always legal for an async runtime to spuriously call poll despite no wakeups. However, you should fix your code instead of relying on that.

thanks for continuing to answer. Actually, I initially used tokio::mpsc. The reason I switched to std::mpsc is that it was faster—I ran benchmarking tests with a high number of transactions. If everything works as expected and the performance is good, is there any reason why I should consider converting back to tokio::mpsc?

Correctness is usually more important than performance. Either use tokio::sync::mpsc in async code (Future, await, poll, etc.) or use std::sync::mpsc in synchronous code (no Future's, await, poll, etc.). Don't mix std::sync::mpsc with polling a Future in the way you did.

Why is it problematic to rely on "that" behavior? What potential issues could arise from depending on the async runtime to spuriously call poll even when there’s no legitimate reason to wake the Future?

Your current code is doing the equivalent of painting your computer red, dropping it off a bridge, getting lucky when an airplane catches it before it hits the ground, and then wondering why the airplane doesn't catch it if you paint it blue instead ;). Red being easier to see is not a legit reason to drop your computer. It's problematic because 1) you clearly want your code to reliably work 2) it doesn't reliably work, seemingly because of your reliance on spurious polls. Correct, reliable code wouldn't change in seemingly unrelated ways when you replace if let with while let.

@narumi FWIW, if your goal is to use an std channel instead of a tokio one, you can make it work, but you'll have to introduce a thread that checks the channel and calls the waker. But there's no way to check it without receiving a message, so you'll need somewhere to store the last received message so the future can return it. Oh, then you'll need to wrap that in a mutex so the thread and the future can both read and write it. Then you have to handle synchronization of both's access to the channel to prevent out of order messages.

@narumi I can pretty much guarantee you that after solving all of those problems, your implementation will be less efficient than tokio's. Just use tokio's!

Thank you all for answering my questions!! I think it would be better to de-future my struct since it’s no longer needed.
